# If $Y$ is Hausdorff, the graph of a continuous function $f:X\to Y$ is closed in $X\times Y$. What if $Y$ has the cofinite topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let X and Y topological spaces. If $Y$ is Hausdorff, we know that the graph of a continuous function $f:X\to Y$ is closed in $X\times Y$. What if $Y$ has the cofinite topology? (that is, the open sets are those whose complement is a finite set).

The same argument that I used to prove the first affirmation do not apply here. Is this result valid? Any hint for a counterexample?

Comment: Consider $X = Y$ and $f$ the identity.

Comment: Yes! The diagonal is closed iff the space is hausdorff =D

Comment: And thus the property characterises Hausdorff spaces. $Y$ is Hausdorff if and only if the graph of every continuous function $f \colon X \to Y$, where $X$ is a topological space, is closed. Want to write an answer, or should I?

Comment: You decide. Due to your hint, I proved the thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property characterises Hausdorff spaces. If every graph of a continuous function to $Y$ is closed, then in particular the graph of the identity function on $Y$ is closed, but that is the diagonal of $Y\times Y$, and a space is Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal is closed.